# What verb to use for 'transportation'?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

What verbs can I use with the noun 'transportation'? For instance, can I use 'do' with 'transportation' this way :

The transportation between point A and point B can be done via/by ....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "do" is a fine verb in this situation; another might be "accomplish."

I would drop "The" from the beginning of the sentence, however, for more natural sounding language, such as: "Transportation between point A and point B can be done/accomplished via _______."

Another option might be to arrange the sentence so that the answer comes first, such as: "_____ provides transport between point A and point B.

Answer (score 0):

We would normally not use "do" there.

Transportation between A and B **is by** __________.

train, truck, air, bus, etc.